# Upload set of files using WinSCP.Session in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm trying to upload three specific files, and get feedback for all three transfers.
With the code below I only get

> Upload of \xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\Customerlocations.txt succeeded

I understand it's not adding transfers to the session but replacing it each time.
I just don't know to adjust this so I get 3 transfers in `$transferResult.Transfers`.

Can someone point me in the correct direction?

```
# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-WinSCPSessionOption  -Protocol Ftp `
    -FtpSecure Implicit `
    -Credential xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx `
    -HostName "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx " `
    -TlsHostCertificateFingerprint "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session 
$session.ExecutablePath = "C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\WinSCP.exe"
try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Download files
    $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
    $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary

    $transferResult =  
        $session.PutFiles("\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\Orders.txt", "/Orders.txt", $False, $transferOptions)
    $transferResult = 
        $session.PutFiles("\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\Assortment.txt", "/Assortment.txt", $False, $transferOptions)
    $transferResult = 
        $session.PutFiles("\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\Customerlocations.txt", "/Customerlocations.txt", $False, $transferOptions)

    # Throw on any error
    $transferResult.Check()

    # Print results
    foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
    {
        Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded"
    }

    # Disconnect, clean up
    $session.Dispose()
}
finally
{
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inspect results of each `Session.PutFiles` call separately. To avoid repeating the code, you can use a loop like this:

```
$paths = @("...\Orders.txt", "...\Assortment.txt", "...\Customerlocations.txt")
foreach ($path in $paths)
{
    $transferResult = $session.PutFiles($path, "/", $False, $transferOptions)
    # Throw on any error
    $transferResult.Check()
 
    # Print results
    foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
    {
        Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded"
    }
}
```